# Running `pbapply` in parallel doesn't allow writing outside of environment

Tags: r, parallel-processing

See the dummy code below. The `pblapply()` function will write to `x1` if I remove the `cl = cores` argument.

Is there a way to force this?

```
input <- c(1,2,3)
myfunc <- function(input) {
  x1 <- list()
  cores <- parallel::makeCluster(2)
  x2 <- unlist(pbapply::pblapply(cl = cores,
                                   input,
                                   function(i) {
                                     x1[[i]] <<- i+3
                                     return(i)
                                   }
  ))
  return(c(x1,x2))
}
myfunc(input)
```

Comment: You can't really run in parallel if you have a shared environment for variables that depend on the order in which the threads are run. Ideally your function should be returning objects that can be automatically collected for you. Focus on the output you require.

Comment: Or write to disk.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?  My reading is that you want x2 to be just a sequence, and x1 in the global environment to be the answer.  Consider instead returning the answer, and if needed, create the sequence separately.